# How do I show an external file creation date on website using just JavaScript?

Tags: html

I don't even know if this is posible.
I'm using straight HTML.  It's really my only option.  No PHP, No .Net, No Java, YES JAVASCRIPT.

I have URL, and I'm trying to display the last modified date.

I came across this code, but it displasy the file, not the last modified date.  Is there something wrong with the code, or is there another way to do this using just HTML and JavaScript?

I'm not able to share the real URL here.

```
<body><p>
<script src="https://www.website.com/wiki_form.html?nodeid=1103951244" type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function getLastMod(){
var myFrm = document.getElementById('myIframe');
var lastModif = new Date(myFrm.contentWindow.document.lastModified);
document.getElementById('LastModified').innerHTML = "Prices correct as at: " + lastModif.toLocaleString();
}
// ]]></script>
<span id="LastModified"></span></p>
<p><iframe id="myIframe" src="https://www.website.com/wiki_form.html?nodeid=1103951244" style="display: none;"></iframe></p></body>
```

Thanks!
Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is not possible with just HTML (HTML is static), and if you're doing any interaction with files using JavaScript you'll need to be hosted on a web-server. If that's the case, you certainly have a reason to use PHP.

Comment: Good News.  I can use Javascript.  I've updated the posting to include this fact and the partial script I've found that seems to get me in the right direction.  But it doesn't display last modified date. ugh.

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing your files via a server and you really can't use PHP, you might be able to use a Server Side Include (SSI); try including the following code in your HTML file:

```
<!--#flastmod file="page.html" -->
```

you'll probably need to change the file extension to .shtml tho, so that the server knows it has to do something special with it.

Comment: Sadly, I don't control the naming convention of the html file.

Comment: It'll depend on the server environment - you might not have to